# How to perform division of two columns that created by UNION ALL operation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a table like below, I wanted to add one column for percentage to apply the formula as field 1/ field 2 (which is 274/45476). What can I do to perform the percentage?

```
Type    Field 1    Field 2      Percentage  
Value   274        45476
```

---

```
select 

"Value" as Type,
sum(case when Type = "Non-decaf" then Total else 0 end) as "Field 1",
sum(case when Type = "All" then Total else 0 end) as "Field 2"

from

(select 

"Non-decaf" as Type,
count(cntrct_id) as Total

from contract

where category = "Non-decaf"


group by 1

UNION ALL

select

"All" as Type,
count(cntrct_id) as Total

from contract

where category = "All"

group by 1) derived

group by 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do this:

```
select 'Value' as type,
       sum(type = 'Non-decaf') as NonDecaf,
       sum(type = 'All') as All,
       sum(type = 'Non-decaf') / sum(type = 'All') as Ratio
from contract;
```

I don't see what the subquery, `union all`, and `group by 1` are doing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Add another nesting:

```
select Type, "Field 1", "Field 2", 1.0*"Field 1" / "Field 2"
from (
    <your query>
)
```

I recommend that you don't use identifiers like "Field 1"

Answer (score 0):

```
select 'Value' as type,
       sum(type = 'Non-decaf') as "Field 1",
       sum(type = 'All') as "Field 2",
       sum(type = 'Non-decaf') / sum(type = 'All') as "Ratio",
       (sum(type = 'Non-decaf') *100 ) / sum(type = 'All') as "Percentage"
from contract;
```

OR (For simplicity,)

```
SELECT TYPE, FIELD_1, FIELD_2, (FIELD_1/FIELD_2) AS RATIO,
((FIELD_1*100)/FIELD_2) AS PERCENTAGE FROM
( select 'Value' as type,
       sum(type = 'Non-decaf') as "Field_1",
       sum(type = 'All') as "Field_2"
   from contract;
);
```